# Disable ComboBox and make the color of the ComboBox Gray

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

1. I have a Combobox. I would like to make the ComboBox disable and change the color to DarkGray when it's disable. I would like this operation to happen when my application launches.
2. Upon selection of a button, it should enable and change the color of the combobox to white again.

Any solution for option 1 would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keywords: Style Triggers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `IsEnabled` property of the `ComboBox` to `false` in your XAML markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb" IsEnabled="False">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

...and then set it to `true` in the click event handler for the `Button`:

```
<Button Content="Enabled" Click="Button_Click" />
```

---

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cmb.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

The default colours should suffice. If you want to change these you will have to modify the `ComboBox`'s `ControlTemplate` as suggested here: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/04/30/changing-the-background-colour-of-a-combobox-in-wpf-on-windows-8/

Comment: Thanks mm8. I tried above options you suggested. It did enable and disable for me but the color doesn't change it to Gray when the combobox is disabled. However, I tried the control template option. It did change the color to Gray when the page loads for the first time. but it doesn't change the color back to white when it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In form constructor you have to disable combobox and change its back color:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Enabled = false;
            comboBox1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
        }
```

When happens your option 2 (for example using event handler) add this code:

```
comboBox1.Enabled = true;
comboBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
```